# Setting up a simple python app with pytest getting error NameError and AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I wanted to get advice on the best way to setup a simple app with pytest.

I can run pytest fine on a single file but I wanted to bootstrap a Python app using:

```
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    app.py
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_app.py
```

But when I run `pytest` I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'func' is not defined
```

**mypkg/__init__.py file**

```
# content of __init__.py
# Empty init file
```

**mypkg/app.py file**

```
# content of app.py
class mypkg:
    def func(x):
        return x + 1
```

**tests/__init__.py file**

```
# content of __init__.py
# Empty init file
```

**tests/test_app.py file**

```
# content of test_app.py
import pytest
import mypkg

def test_answer():
    assert func(4) == 5
```

I'm using Python 3.5.

Do I need a `setup.py` and if I try calling `mypkg.func(4)` instead I get an `AttributeError: module`mypkg`has no attribute 'func'`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with pytest, or with testing at all. It is a fundamental rule in Python that if you want to access a name you need to import it; you haven't imported `func`, so it gives a name error.

However, for some reason you have defined `func` as part of a class. You cannot import a method separately from its class; but, there is *no reason* for that to be a method in a class at all. Just define it as a standalone function, and import that.

Note, even standing on its own, `func` is inside `app`, not directly inside `mypkg`. So you need to import it where it actually is.

```
from mypkg.app import func
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel :) I understand now that the period between mypkg and app = the directory mypkg/app. Also, I've remove the class and have the method stands alone now.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `func` inside `mypkg` class that resides inside `mypkg/app.py` module, thus you need to rewrite your tests as follows

```
# content of test_app.py
import pytest
import mypkg

def test_answer():
    obj = mypkg.app.mypkg()
    assert obj.func(4) == 5
```